# Should I change the process priority of Apache Tomcat in Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2003, tomcat

I have a web app running on tomcat/Windows  that is experiencing performance issues. Will setting the process priority help or will this interfere with my system stability.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only help if something else on the server is taking away processor cycles and you are certain you don't want that something getting the cycles.
In many years of using Windows server, I've never increased the priority of a task for anything other than experimentation.

Are you certain that tomcat is processor starved and not waiting on disk IO or memory swap?

\\Greg

Comment: Thanks. I believe it is a memory issue. Is it good or bad that Tomcat has high Mem Usage? I want it to utilize all the memory it can, and not artificially contrain it. I have 2 gigs in there, as you can see it is using up 1.4 gigs. I wonder if adding 2 more gigs would help.

Comment: Adding RAM will help if either you experience GC pauses or you can increase some cache setting thanks to the bigger heap or something like that.

Comment: It is not good or bad that it is using a lot of RAM.  The question is whether the rest of the system is memory constrained.  Looking at the number of hard page faults (where pages are being read from disk swap space) is high and sustained.  I imagine there are some good articles on Technet that discuss system performance and finding the bottleneck.